# Table View Not scrolling to the last row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am making an iPhone App.

I have used table view in some View Controller.

In iPhone it is scrolling Ok.

I have converted the app to the iPad and autoresized the table view via IB and changed the size of CELL.

It is not showing me the last cell and giving me a jerky feel so I could not select it.

I don not know where I am going wrong?

Comment: You should modify your question to include a little bit of code to show how you are doing your cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection methods for your table view.  I suspect it's either a cell dequeue issue or you're not sending back the right value for the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Actually It is a problem of resizing autoresizing.
In my case [image]

Table view is showing the correct result now.
You can see below tabe view I have used Image view, so by autoresizing property (IB) some part of the table hides below the Imageview because of extra stretching.

Otherwise table view is working perfectly well.s

Comment: it is better to edit your question than answer your own question. Have you tried querying the size of the image view and adjusting your table view according to that ?

Comment: Ya next time I will take care..definately. @Krammer No, I have seen the auto resizing attribute of table view which has shown me that it is keeping the same distance from bottom of the view. So, from that I came to know that if everything is resizing so there must be a table view behind the image view. Thanks.